# Entity Framework 0..1 to 0..1 relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am facing a problem when trying to create an entity and set one of its association properties which is a 0..1 relationship to another entity

Both the ends of the association is 0..1

Here is what I try to do

```
var entityA = new EntityA();
var entityB = new EntityB();
entityA.associatedEntity = entityB;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

It works just fine, both of the entities are saved but when I retrieve entityA I get its associatedEntity property set to null

Why is that? it happens to me only on 0..1 to 0..1 relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Is lazy-loading enabled for your ObjectContext? If not you have to explicitly load the related entities. If you are using POCO or code-first there might also be a configuration problem, which prevens EF from creating a proper proxy type which performs the lazy-loading once you access the `associatedEntity` property.

You can eager-load related entities in EF using the `Include(string)` method on one of the context's `ObjectSet` objects, like:

```
context.EntityASet.Include("associatedEntity").Single(e => e.Id == 10);
```

Comment: I am having the same problem and attempted your solution.  It did not resolve my issue.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can use EF 4.1/2 for implement easy as easy relations with putting attribute top of properties of entity classes.
for more information: 
  **[using features of EF 4.1/2](http://arash.im/2011/11/why-not-use-entity-framework-features-part2/)**